# How does the fiber bundle perspective on geometric phase lead to a certain connection one-form?

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature, berry-pancharatnam-phase

I'm trying to understand why the relevant connection one-form when calculating geometric phase in quantum systems is
$$\mathcal{A}_\psi(X):=i \text{Im}\langle \psi | X\rangle.$$

**Set-up:** I'll set the stage and explain what I do understand. Let $\mathcal{H}$ be the Hilbert space corresponding to some physical system, $\mathcal{S}(\mathcal{H}) = \{\psi\in \mathcal{H}|\langle \psi|\psi\rangle =1\}$, and $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{H})= \mathcal{S}(\mathcal{H})/U(1)$ (*i.e.* the space of one-dimensional projectors in $\mathcal{H}$). We have the principal $U(1)$-bundle
$$\pi:\mathcal{S}(\mathcal{H})\rightarrow \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{H}),\\
|\psi\rangle \mapsto |\psi \rangle \langle \psi |.$$
My understanding is that the choice of a connection is a choice of horizontal subspace in the tangent space $T_\psi\mathcal{S}(\mathcal{H})$. This gives us information about how to move between fibers when implementing the notion of a horizontal lift from a path in the base manifold $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{H})$.

**Point of confusion/main questions:** I read in multiple sources that the tangent space $T_\psi \mathcal{S}(\mathcal{H})$ can be identified as a linear subspace of $\mathcal{H}$.
Apparently the natural Hermitian scalar product $\langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle$ in $\mathcal{H}$ is used to define a natural connection on $T_\psi \mathcal{S}(\mathcal{H})$.
I then see it claimed that $X$ is a horizontal vector at $\psi$ if $\langle \psi | X\rangle=0$. **Why can we say this? Aren't we mixing objects that live in $\mathcal{S}(\mathcal{H})$ and $T_\psi \mathcal{S}(\mathcal{H})$ in a sloppy way?** I think my confusion really stems from the fact that I thought the Hermitian scalar product should map $T_\psi\mathcal{S}(\mathcal{H}) \times T_\psi\mathcal{S}(\mathcal{H}) \rightarrow U(1)$ but here we are mapping $\mathcal{H}\times \mathcal{H}\rightarrow U(1)$. A connection should give us a horizontal direction in the tangent space $T_\psi \mathcal{S}(\mathcal{H})$ but here we're looking at orthogonal elements to $\psi$ (*i.e. not* in the tangent space). What's going on here?

---

**Additional thoughts:**
Here's my intuition: vectors in $\mathcal{H}$ can be different from $\psi$ by multiplying $\psi$ by some phase (*i.e.* staying within the fiber in $\mathcal{S}(\mathcal{H})$) or  by actually pointing along a different ray. In a sense (a horizontal one...), $\langle \psi|X\rangle=0$ tells us how to move directly from $\psi$ to some other ray.

From this point we can define a horizontal curve in $\mathcal{S}(\mathcal{H})$ where $\langle \psi(t) |\dot{\psi}(t)\rangle = 0$. (Recall that the velocity vector of a curve on a manifold defines a tangent vector.)  With the assumption that $\langle \psi | \psi \rangle = 1$, we have $\text{Im}\langle \psi(t)|\dot{\psi}(t)\rangle=0$. Now we finally define the $u(1)$-valued connection one-form on $\mathcal{S}(\mathcal{H})$ as
\begin{align}
\mathcal{A}_\psi(X):=i \text{Im}\langle \psi | X\rangle
\end{align}
whose kernel is the set of horizontal vectors.